# Word merge from vb.net windows application

Tags: windows, vb.net, ms-word, mailmerge, word-2010

I have a word merge from vb.net application that works fine on other machines but on mine the source document suppress spaces in between column headers and errors out 
expected header in source doc
sampledata1 sampledata2 samp3

created
sampledata1sampledata2samp3

> Private mstrMailMergeFields As String = "CL_Number, Name, CO_NAME"
>          Dim strTemplateFileName As String
>           Dim strSourceFileName As String

```
    Dim strSignatureFilePath As String = ""
    Dim wordApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application = Nothing
    Dim wordDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = Nothing
    Dim wordDocSource As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = Nothing
    Dim wordDocResult As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = Nothing
```

any direction on help is appreciated

Comment: hi, you need to add the relevant code to your question so that we have a chance of duplicating the problem and finding what's wrong. Without the code there is pretty much no chance. Thanks

Comment: In addition to what David says, we also need to know the errors and what line of code triggers them. Also, it's not clear what "suppress spaces between column headers" means - more detail on that and/or a screen shot would help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out the regional settings in word has a field for separator was "!" instead of "," this was messing the header changed it and it worked fine.